# Python Django pysec element

Tags: python, django

Sorry for the basic of the question but In order not to start learning in the wrong direction I would like to ask about [pysec:](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec)

Can it be installed just like Django  to use it **or** you must open it up and learn/comprehend the code in the `py` files and customize it accordingly to your needs to work?

Do I need to use SQL or some kind of database, or I can skip that step since I only need to see the data and not save them most of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add `DATA_DIR = '/you/directory/to/download/files/to'` to your Django settings.py and set up a database.

The [documentation](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec/blob/master/README.md) for this app describes the install process.

Comment: I have read the documentation so many times i am trying to understand it-wink. What kind of a database? mySQL is the only one i know of from long time ago... Do you propose a new one? Which is easy to learn and reliable?

Comment: I have the `pysec-master` file (the one that is downloaded from GitHub) in the `C:\Python27` directory do i need to put it on certain place or not?

Comment: I highly suggest you run through the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/) to understand how Django works. Django supports PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite. Database connections are set up through your settings.py.